# How to style radio buttons differently if they fit in a single row?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/firaripayi/1/edit?html,css,output)

I'd like to style radio buttons differently if they fit in a single row. For example:

[image]

The first container doesn't have enough space to fit all the radio buttons in a single row. Therefore, they appear vertically as normal radio buttons.

The second container has enough space. Therefore, the radio buttons appear as buttons.

Is that possible to achieve this behaviour **using CSS only**?

If not, Javascript "hack" is welcome.

[**PLAYGROUND HERE**](http://jsbin.com/firaripayi/1/edit?html,css,output)

---

**HTML**

```
<div class="container radio">
  <div>
    <input id="a1" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="a1">Yes,</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="a2" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="a2">it</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="a3" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="a3">is</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="a4" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="a4">possible</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="a5" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="a5">to</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="a6" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="a6">achieve</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="a7" type="radio" name="radio">
    <label for="a7">this</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container buttons">
  <div>
    <input id="b1" type="radio" name="buttons">
    <label for="b1">Yes,</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="b2" type="radio" name="buttons">
    <label for="b2">it</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="b3" type="radio" name="buttons">
    <label for="b3">is</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input id="b4" type="radio" name="buttons">
    <label for="b4">possible</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS (LESS)**

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;

  &.radio {
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  &.buttons {
    flex-direction: row;

    > div {
      input {
        display: none;

        &:checked + label {
          background-color: #ADFFFE;
        }
      }

      label {
        padding: 5px 10px;
        margin: 0 1px;
        background-color: #ccc;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: While the link to the JS Bin reproduction is much appreciated, you must post your relevant code in the question itself in order to guard against link-rot. If your goal is to provide a demo (again: much appreciated!) then you could simply use Stack Overflow's "[Stack Snippets](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)" feature.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Not possible in CSS, but it doesn't take much JavaScript.

In CSS, add `flex-shrink: 0` to `> div`.  This will prevent `.container`'s children from shrinking smaller than their extent.

In JavaScript:

1. Apply the `buttons` class.
2. Use [**Element.getBoundingClientRect**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) to determine if the last child of `.container` is outside the extent of `.container`.  If so, switch to the `radio` class.  (You also need to take the right padding into account.  Thanks to @Moob for pointing that out.)

**Javascript**

```
var container = document.querySelector('.container'),
    lastChild= document.querySelector('.container > :last-child'),
    paddingRight= parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(container, null).getPropertyValue('padding-right')),
    timer;

window.onresize = function() {
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer= setTimeout(function() {
    container.classList.remove('radio');
    container.classList.add('buttons');
    if (container.getBoundingClientRect().right-paddingRight <
        lastChild.getBoundingClientRect().right) {
      container.classList.add('radio');
      container.classList.remove('buttons');
    }
  });
}
```

[**Updated JSBin**](http://jsbin.com/wujigaliha/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Good solution. Didn't know about `flex-shrink` (still avoiding flex-boxes in most of my work). I've used it to improve my own answer. Thanks.

Comment: @Rick Nice! I tried to run your JS every time window resizes, but I see a strange flickering effect: http://jsbin.com/garuvexaha/1/edit?html,js,output
Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: `onresize` runs constantly while resizing.  Best to add a timeout.  See update at http://jsbin.com/cibudaforu/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: @RickHitchcock No flickering now, but I can still see undesired behaviour: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1893981/Screenshots/x-10.png (should be radio buttons)

Comment: I've switched from `scrollWidth` to `getBoundingClientRect`.  That solves the problem.

Answer (score 6):

I can't think of a CSS only solution but you could use JS to test if the items would fit in a row and apply the 'radio' or 'buttons' classname accordingly:

Forgive my rough JS - its inelegant and for modern browsers only but you get the idea:

```
var containers = document.querySelectorAll(".container"),
test = function(){
    for (i = 0; i < containers.length; ++i) {
      var container = containers[i],
          divs = container.querySelectorAll("div"),
          iw = 0;
      container.classList.remove("radio");
      container.classList.add("buttons");
      //get the sum width of the div
      for (d = 0; d < divs.length; ++d) {
        iw+=divs[d].offsetWidth;
      }
      var style = window.getComputedStyle(container, null);
      var ow = parseInt(style.getPropertyValue("width"));
      if(ow<=iw){
          container.classList.add("radio");
          container.classList.remove("buttons");            
      }
    }
};

window.onresize = function(event) {
    test();
};
test();
```

http://jsbin.com/zofixakama/3/edit?html,css,js,output
(resize the window / panel to see the effect)

**Update**: If you add `.container div {flex-shrink:0;}` to the style the JS can be much simpler as we don't have to measure the combined width of the divs (thanks @rick-hitchcock). However, although the code is more elegant, it does not take the container's `padding` into account.

See: http://jsbin.com/zofixakama/5/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @humble.rumble.6x3 agreed, the updated version (v5) does not take the padding into account however the code example (and link to v3) does. I've updated my answer to reflect this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand what you're asking correctly, you can change your `flex-direction` portion to `row` instead of `column`. This will cause them to align inside the box.

You'll have to do some more styling to properly get the labels to appear the way you want, but this should put them in the row for you. [I've updated the playground with my changes](http://jsbin.com/rivacaheho/1/edit).

Comment: I'm afraid you misunderstood the question. In my example there are two containers. One of them has the class `radio`, and the other one `buttons`. I don't want to have these classes on the containers. I added them only for the demo purposes. The question is how to create the behaviour you see in the demo without adding these classes manually.

Comment: Ahh ok. I understand now. I will update my answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

Try the following example..............
------------HTML-----------

```
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" /> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-row">
        <div class="col">
                <input type="Radio">This
            </div>
            <div class="col" style="padding-top: 2px;">
                <input type="Radio">Is
            </div>  

            <div class="col">
                <input type="Radio">Simply
            </div>
            <div class="col" style="padding-top: 2px;">
                <input type="Radio">Possible
            </div>  

        </div>  
</body>
</html>
```

-------CSS-------------

```
.table-row{  
     display:table-row;     
     /* text-align: center; */
}
.col{
    display:table-cell;
    /* border: 1px solid #CCC; */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't it work to test for width then if necessary remove the radio button icon and replace with a graphic or shape?

```
.checkbox {
    display:none;
}

.label {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    background: url('picture.png');
}
```

It's probably not that simple but I use that for check boxes and it seems to work in that situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this only by using css and no need of scripting.

HTML: You have to place the input within  tag which will contain the text.

```
<div>
<label for="a1">
    <input id="a1" type="radio" name="radio">Yes,
</label>  </div>
```

CSS: Here in CSS we will have to hide the radio button, so that only the text will be visible. When the user clicks on the text, it actually clicks the radio button.

```
div lable input#a1{
   display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is pretty solution CSS only, but you have to know maximum amount of elements in row. It is based on counter, but not on real size.

For example, if you are sure, that you can put 4 elements into a row, in any case, you may use following selector:

if amount is more less or equal 4:

```
div:nth-last-child(-n+5):first-child,
div:nth-last-child(-n+5):first-child ~ div {
    }
```

if amount is more then 4:

```
div:nth-last-child(n+5),
div:nth-last-child(n+5) ~ div {
}
```

try this: http://jsbin.com/fozeromezi/2/edit (just remove/add divs)

Comment: ... but if the elements are of unknown or unequal width we'd have no way of knowing how many will fit.

Comment: It depends. You can always use "overflow ellipsis" in combination with "display inline-block" and fixed width. That's why I mentioned, that this answer is suitable only for certain conditions, but it is in pure CSS.